# What is Maxwell's construction, in general?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, physical-chemistry

In the following, we consider everything on a molar basis (divide through by $N$) so that system size is factored out.

In Chapter 9.4 of his famous textbook, Callen (essentially, since he doesn't use the phrase) discusses Maxwell's construction as it relates to the van der Waals equation of state. In particular, Callen shows how the $P$-$v$ characteristic (at fixed $T$) implied by the vdW equation of state is defective (or, at least, deficient), insofar as it includes some states which are not minimum $G$ (at a given point in the $P$-$T$ plane). Callen then introduces the Maxwell construction to show how a modification can be made to it so as to represent the system with a real, physical $P$-$v$ characteristic.

My question is about how I am supposed to extrapolate/extend what I learned in this section. What does the Maxwell construction tell us/how is it useful, or is it just an aside? Am I simply supposed to understand it as a way of converting possible $PvT$ equations of state into real, physical ones? If this latter presumption is true, it does largely then seem like a curiosity?

Comment: Does my answer to this question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/378123/van-der-waals-model-for-liquid-gas-phase-transition-understanding-maxwell-cons?rq=1 provide the information you are looking for?

Comment: See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/253617/maxwells-area-construction-why?rq=1

Comment: It seems both answers just explain *what* it does, whereas I am more asking about the general domain of applicability (is it simply meant to modify any $PvT$ model which is deficient like vdW)? @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90

Answer (score 2):

Maxwell's construction is equivalent to restoring the proper convexity of the underlying fundamental equation. As such, it is crucial to transform an approximate and locally unphysical fundamental equation into an acceptable model for the thermodynamic behavior of a system and, in particular, to allow for first-order phase transitions.

The breaking of convexity is a feature of the phenomenological van der Waals equation and the expected behavior of mean-field theories. For example, the well-known Curie-Weiss theory for the para-/ferro-magnetic transition provides an analytical, non-convex free energy as a function of magnetization below the transition temperature. The analogous Maxwell construction restores the proper convexity and introduces the correct non-analyticity in correspondence with the first-order phase transition.

Answer (score 1):

*Maxwell construction* refers to the graphical determination of the phase boundary in the van der Waals equation of state, and more generally to any analytic equation of sate that produces an isotherm with an unstable branch. According to the Maxwell construction the shaded areas above and below the tie line are equal. The tie line can then be constructed graphically by trial and error until these areas are equal:

[image]

This construction is a graphical interpretation of the condition
$$
   \mu_L(T,P^\text{sat},v_L) = \mu_V(T,P^\text{sat},v_V)
$$

The standard calculation of thermodynamic properties, for example fugacity, begins from the ideal gas state where the property is known ($f=P$) and one adds corrections ("residual properties") calculated by integrating deviations from ideal gas law, as expressed by the equation of state. To reach the liquid side this integration must pass through the phase boundary. Real (i.e experimental) isotherms contain a flat tie line from the saturated vapor (state D) to the saturated liquid (state A). On the other hand, analytic isotherms are smooth and go from $D$ to $A$ via a path (DCBA) that contains metastable and unstable branches. The integration that calculates deviations from ideal gas must pass through this analytic region. The Maxwell construction is a graphical method to identify the end points $D$ and $A$ that correspond to the saturated phases.

Comment: Maxwell construction is not a graphical method. It corresponds to using the unphysical isotherms to obtain the physical condition of equal chemical potential at the phase transition. The fact that the condition of equal chemical potential can be recast in terms of finding equal areas and that such a condition, in turn, can be easily visualized does not imply that the construction reduces to a graphical method. It is a quantitative condition amenable to accurate numerical calculations.

Comment: Semantics: it is a graphical *construction*, as in drawing a straight line that divides a shape into two equal areas, and it is exact. Engineers employ various types of solutions to mathematical problems: analytic, numerical, and graphical. Graphical does not mean approximate. Newton's method for the roots off an equation has a beautiful graphical solution that converges to the true answer.

Comment: The graphic illustration of an analytic method is not the same as a graphical method. Maybe it is semantics, but I would keep well separated the two concepts.

Comment: Then I am not sure what you mean by "graphical method".